# Set android:layout_weight for LinearLayout from C#

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I have LinearLayout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_buttons_view"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

I found it in my code by Id

```
linearLayoutProfile = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linear_layout_profile);
```

For example such property as visible is working. It is real component and C# found it. But I need to change android:layout_weight to - 2. I do it such way

```
linearLayoutProfileButtonsView.WeightSum = 2;
```

But it is not working. How I can do it?

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can access any **LayoutParams** from code . You just have to be very aware of what **LayoutParams** your accessing. This is normally achieved by checking the containing ViewGroup if it has a LayoutParams inner child then that's the one you should use. In your case it's LinearLayout .LayoutParams.

Check teh following code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayoutProfile = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linear_layout_profile);

LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                      LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                      LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                      2f   //set layout_weight here
                      );
linearLayoutProfile.LayoutParameters = param;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the correct way of doing it is passing it in the constructor as shown below:

```
linearLayoutProfile.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.
LayoutParam ( ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, 1f); // 1f here is the weight
```

Things to note:

- Weight should always be given as a float value.
- the layout params that you assign to any control should always be based on its parent so if the Parent of the `linearLayoutProfile` is `RelativeLayout` for instance then you should use `RelativeLayout''s Layout params in the above example.

Goodluck

Revert in case of any queries